# Help understanding the Half-Orc Shock Trooper charger rogue build

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I'm going to make my second ever character in D&D 4e. Based on few questions I asked erlier here I decided to make a charger rogue [Half-Orc Shock Trooper](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27050849/What_Is_Yours_Can_Be_Mine%3a_A_Thiefs_Handbook&post_num=10#486645241). Not everything is clear to me in this build, so my questions are:

1. Why does this guy have 8 trained skills when *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* states that a Thief has 6 trained skills?
2. I couldn't find sources (and descriptions) for a few feats: Improved Defenses, Superior Will, and Disciple of Freedom, as well as one power called Chameleon. Can you please give me sources or their effects? I couldn't find them in [DDi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx).
3. What is meant by "Epic Heroism (Strength)" and "Epic Heroism (Dexterity)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you linked is **Level 30**, and, consequently, has rather a bit more going on than is immediately apparent. I applaud your courage in trying out a highly optimized character as your second character ever, in my experience, theoretically optimized characters take a fair bit of skill to play: well done.

When playing with theoretical optimization, most people use the character builder.

This thief has an additional skill from "[Battle Awareness](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=911)" a multiclass fighter feat as well as the thief's "Skill Mastery" level 2 class feature.

Epic Heroism is a way of indicating the class feature choices at epic level, such that he gets stat boosts.

I recommend, instead of looking at this level 30 build looking at this [level 1 build](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22105109/DPR_King_Candidates_2.0&post_num=1045#470447865) instead. It will likely be far more understandable and applicable at your level. There *are* higher damaging thief builds out there, of course, but that is quite approachable and doesn't require fiddly themes.

Be advised that the charger rogue is a *significant* one-trick pony: you will, every turn, charge. You must find interacting with the environment fun and rolling lots of dice fun, as there is little tactical chocie in this build. On the other hand, if you are comfortable moving your tactical choice onto positioning and environmental interactions, the charger thief is a simple and fun way to absolutely kill everything in your path.

In terms of the feats, The [DDI compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) has all of them:

- Superior Will: Published in Heroes of the Fallen Lands, page(s) 318, Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms, page(s) 319.
- Improved Defenses: Published in Heroes of the Fallen Lands, page(s) 315, Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms, page(s) 315.
- Disciple of Freedom: Published in Heroes of the Fallen Lands, page(s) 312, Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms, page(s) 312.
- Chameleon: Published in Player's Handbook, page(s) 120, Class Compendium. Updated in Class Compendium.

Comment: Making lvl one character isnt that hard, its much harder not to screw up somewhere in the middle thats why i decided to pick lvl 30 build.
And what about source on that feats? I mean can you please tell me from what book or magazine are they taken?

Comment: The problem is that you should look for builds that have level by level breakdowns to help with item selection/wishlists. Still, this is not a bad start.

Comment: Yes, yes I have. Look at the answer.